# zipline : change input data for built in factors

Tags: zipline, back-testing, quantopian

I'm trying to use Zipline API in my local environment.

I have successfully ingested my custom csv data and the backtesting works fine without using the Pipeline API.

However, I am lost on how I should make use of built in factors when using the Pipeline API.

To be more specific, I'd like to change the input variable in the following example.

```
sma_10 = SimpleMovingAverage(inputs=[USEquityPricing.close], window_length=10)
sma_30 = SimpleMovingAverage(inputs=[USEquityPricing.close], window_length=30)
```

That is, instead of using `USEquityPricing.close`, I'd like to use `MY_CSV_BUNDLE.close`. Is that possible, and if so, how should I implement it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This quantopian community question gives a hint for the problem :

https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/issues/911